# OpenCV4Android - capturing images in rectangles (face detection)

Tags: android, c++, opencv, face-detection

I've been using OpenCV C/C++ in the past, and currently I'm  trying Android. I am detecting face features. I use OpenCV example for face detection and I am detecting features via cascades. What I want to ask you is:

1) how to capture area in reactangle to variable/device memory:

In OpenCV it worked like that:

```
cvSetImageROI(img1, cvRect(10, 15, 150, 250));

IplImage *img2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1),
                           img1->depth,
                           img1->nChannels);
cvCopy(img1, img2, NULL);
```

In Android example I have array with rectangles of found faces:

```
Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++)
Core.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 3);
```

But I have no clue how to save it because I cant work on IplImage. Can you guide me a bit about it or give me some source which I can study?

2) if there is any way to set onClick on areas which were found on the camera view, so I can click on choosen face, at write it to some kind of variable or save it in memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think, you're looking for [mRgba.submat(facesArray[i])](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#submat%28org.opencv.core.Rect%29)

(very biased personal opinion: you're still using IplImages (aka c-api) ? whaa. bad habit. move over to the c++ api!)

Comment: Yeah it helps a lot, it allows me to write area in reactangle to variable. If you could also tell me the way to display it, because when I do:  if (facesArray[0]!=null) { mChosenFace=mRgba.submat(facesArray[0]); return mChosenFace; } my camera view freeze. Well iI have problem as u can see, in C++ I was using book and I had reference, now I don't know the basics of writing and displaying image. Do you have any source where I could learn it?

Comment: you can't just say :  if (facesArray[0]!=null) . if there were no faces found, there is no facesArray[0], that's an illegal instruction already. you have to check facesArray.length first